# Having trouble indexing specific vectors in dataset

Tags: python, dictionary, vector, indexing, cluster-analysis

This is what the dataset looks like. Type: dic len: 7500[1]
I am having trouble trying to index specific values within the arrays! There are 46 vectors per array (23 x/y pairs). If possible I am trying to select a specific vector for all the 'sequences' in the dataset. Or ideally I am trying to separate the 46 vectors into 23 different variables to cluster them!

Some of the code that I have tried:

```
for sequence, vectors in df.items():
    df1 = np.array_split(vectors, 23, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

- The problem was I couldn't get python to recognize the x, y.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame
```

- I tried converting this into a dataframe but still could not index it.

```
    'sequence_7303': array([[ 38.382774  ,  -1.6118518 ,   3.3157895 , ...,   7.757037  ,
         -26.928228  , -35.36      ],
        [ 38.282295  ,  -1.6118518 ,   3.3157895 , ...,   7.6562963 ,
         -27.591389  , -35.22904   ],
        [ 38.282295  ,  -1.7125926 ,   3.3157895 , ...,   7.6562963 ,
         -28.264595  , -35.108147  ],
        ...,
        [ 51.84689   ,  -0.60444444,  49.33493   , ..., -16.42074   ,
          51.997604  , -24.127409  ],
        [ 51.94737   ,  -0.9066667 ,  49.736843  , ..., -16.42074   ,
          52.36938   , -24.973629  ],
        [ 51.94737   ,  -1.1081481 ,  50.038277  , ..., -16.32      ,
          52.751198  , -25.81985   ]], dtype=float32),
    'sequence_7302': array([[ 40.100502 ,   1.3293233,  -7.8090453, ...,   2.863158 ,
         -27.753767 ,   5.419549 ],
        [ 39.994976 ,   1.2270677,  -8.125628 , ...,   2.7609022,
         -28.830153 ,   5.153684 ],
        [ 39.889446 ,   1.2270677,  -8.547738 , ...,   2.7609022,
         -29.906534 ,   4.88782  ],
        ...,
        [ 51.497486 ,   3.2721806,  34.190952 , ...,  -2.5563908,
          42.569847 ,  19.121803 ],
        [ 51.603016 ,   3.3744361,  34.296482 , ...,  -2.5563908,
          43.023617 ,  19.172932 ],
        [ 51.603016 ,   3.4766917,  34.296482 , ...,  -2.4541354,
          43.477386 ,  19.22406  ]], dtype=float32),
     'sequence_1465': array([[ 33.635933  ,  -0.09883721, -23.654943  , ...,  -3.8546512 ,
         -24.752851  ,  -3.8546512 ],
        [ 33.53612   ,  -0.09883721, -24.153992  , ...,  -4.3488374 ,
         -25.13213   ,  -4.7046514 ],
        [ 33.43631   ,   0.        , -24.752851  , ...,  -4.94186   ,
         -25.511406  ,  -5.5546513 ],
        ...,
        [ 50.40399   ,   8.203488  ,   2.8944867 , ...,  12.156977  ,
          48.95675   ,  30.175     ],
        [ 50.40399   ,   8.401163  ,   2.9942966 , ...,  12.3546505 ,
          49.276142  ,  30.352907  ],
        [ 50.30418   ,   8.5       ,   3.1939163 , ...,  12.552325  ,
          49.60551   ,  30.540699  ]], dtype=float32),
     'sequence_642': array([[ 39.011856  ,  -1.8658537 ,   1.7638341 , ..., -20.939024  ,
         -17.534584  ,  23.737804  ],
        [ 39.011856  ,  -1.7621951 ,   1.5563241 , ..., -20.835365  ,
         -17.596838  ,  23.665243  ],
        [ 39.011856  ,  -1.6585366 ,   1.3488142 , ..., -20.731709  ,
         -17.659092  ,  23.603048  ],
        ...,
        [ 43.265812  ,   2.1768293 ,   0.        , ..., -18.34756   ,
           2.2618577 ,   9.598781  ],
        [ 43.369564  ,   2.1768293 ,  -0.10375495, ..., -18.34756   ,
           3.0503953 ,   9.515854  ],
        [ 43.369564  ,   2.1768293 ,  -0.20750989, ..., -18.34756   ,
           3.838933  ,   9.432927  ]], dtype=float32),
```

Comment: Please do not use a picture: insert the text directly. Moreover, please precise exactly what you tried to do.

Comment: I have updated the post. I appreciate any help.